# Optimize data retrieval from different servers with more than 10M records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT party_code , max(date) AS date    FROM     
server1.table1 WITH (nolock) GROUP  BY party_code    

UNION    
SELECT party_code , max(date) AS date   FROM     
server2.table1 WITH (nolock) GROUP  BY party_code    

UNION    
SELECT party_code , max(date) AS date    FROM     
server3.table1 WITH (nolock) GROUP  BY party_code
```

Like shown above I have similarly 17 tables on different servers, so I union them to get records. The total data sums up to more than 36 [crores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore) (360 millions) which effects the database execution time and ability to retrieve records. Can someone help me as to how to optimize this. Or any other solution to it.

Comment: Can different servers have same `party_code`s and what happen when they do? Do you need separate rows with each `max(date)` or one `max(date)` for all of them?

Comment: yes nenad we have same party codes in different servers. yes i need seperate rows with each max dates

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use `Union`, instead you can use `Union all` and finally delete
   duplicate records if any.
2. Insert all records in a stage(temp) table and finally delete duplicate records if any.
3. If number of records are huge you can you SSIS for faster process

Comment: how do i use it in ssis

Comment: you can use execute sql task with different connection manager and load the data into a stage table. SSIS will be faster than normal T-sql code. And also there is union operator to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) on your tables. So if you do not have it already create this index on all your tables:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_party_code__date 
  ON server1.table1 (party_code) INCLUDE (date)
```

Second, replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` operators. Union does the sorting and comparing of datasets which you don't need if you need to keep records from each server separately.

If that doesn't help enough, maybe you can look in some of the other options:

- Maybe you can first `UNION ALL` all the records (adding `ServerID` column in the process) and then do one `GROUP BY` on the dataset (on `party_code` and `ServerID`), but I can't tell for sure whatever this will be better or worse (you'll have to test).
- Try using [indexed views.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)
- Staging tables that will be calculated and filled during night?